# Where to put basic validation on controller or in domain model

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, cqrs, axon

**Service A -**

Have a Rest API to handle the Command-A , on the controller I do some basic field validation (null check , email format check etc).
After validation  controller send the Command-A to Command-Handler-A.

**Service B** - also have the same way of Command Handling like service A.

Now , Service B have a saga which on some event send the Command-A to Service A.
Service A handles that Command-A using the Command-Handler-A.
But in this case Command-A by pass the basic validation which I put on controller of Service-A.

**Question -**

1. Is I have to put all the validation in Command Handler/Domain Model ? Or
2. I have to call the Rest API of Service-A from Service-B saga. (Which make a single entry point in service). Or
3. Any other solution ?

**Using - Axon Framework 4.2 and Axon Server with Spring Boot.**

Answer (score 1):

> Where to put basic validation on controller or in domain model

Service-A is responsible for ensuring its own pre-conditions.

One of those pre-conditions is that it received a correct message.  In the case of Controller-A, you should expect to have a [parse](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/) that converts the bytes that were received into a validated Command-A.  That function might be implemented by the controller itself, or it might be delegated to some other component  -- but it will certainly be within the *application* component, not in the *domain model*.